# Function to determine the color of a pixel in racket?

Tags: colors, racket

So I'm trying to find or create a function that determines the color of the pixels a certain point is on, any ideas on what it might be/how to make it in Drracket? I'm trying to make it so I find the color of the pixel the point is traveling across, then if the color changes to a new one.

Comment: Are you using `pict`, `2htdp/image`, `racket/draw`, or some other image library?

Comment: I'm using 2htdp/image

Answer (score 1):

An `bitmap-dc` has a `get-pixel` method.

Answer (score 1):

In the on-mouse of the big-bang, you could use image->color-list and use list-ref to get a specific point.

```
(define img (circle 20 'solid 'red))
(define width (image-width img))
(define height (image-height img))
(define (color-indexes l)
(if (empty? l) empty (cons (take l width)
                           ;r-rest not a function but it drops width items 
                           ;from a list.You will have to make that
                           (color-indexes (r-rest l width)))))
 ;put this where you want the color
 (list-ref (list-ref (image->color-list) (sub1 x)))(sub1 y))
```

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that. The placement of colors in the list depends on the width and height of the image. If you only have an `x` and a `y` coordinate, how do you get the position in the list?

Comment: If you know the the image width, make a function that takes the width of an image and a list. Make the function group every width item into a new list so you will wind up with multiple list in a single list(2d array). For example `(take lst (sub1 width))` Then you could recursively do this until the list is empty. Then use `(list-ref (list-ref lst (sub1 x))(sub1 y)))` to get the exact pixel you wanted. The reason we subtract 1 is because the indexes start at 0.

Comment: No, a better way would be to multiply the `y` coordinate with the width and add the `x` coordinate to that. Also no need for the `sub1` if `x` and `y` are themselves 0-indexed. Please edit your answer to improve it.

Comment: Sounds good, however i will not be changing my answer as this is how i would have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `2htdp/image`, you have to use [`image->color-list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#(def._((lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt)._image-~3ecolor-list))). However, the list doesn't give you the colors in terms of `x` and `y` coordinates. You need to calculate the position of the pixel within the list, by taking the width of the image into account. The color-list it returns goes across the rows, starting at the top with top-left to top-right, and then the next row down, left to right, and so on.

The (zero-indexed) position within that list for `(x,y)` is `x + width*y`, or:

```
(+ x (* width y))
```

In context:

```
;; get-pixel : Image Number Number -> Color
(define (get-pixel img x y)
   (list-ref (image->color-list img)
             (+ x (* (image-width img) y))))
```